# What's the best way to get the type contained by an std::optional?

Tags: c++, templates

I'm wondering what the simplest way is of getting the type contained by an std::optional. The solution I thought of is:

```
#include <type_traits>
template <typename Optional_T>
    struct GetOptionalContainedType
    {
        using type = std::remove_reference<decltype(Optional_T::value())>::type;
    };
```

This requires the inclusion of the <type_traits> header, (I need std::remove_reference) for this method because ::value() returns a reference to the type, right?

Comment: According to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional) it has a `value_type` typedef so `typename Optional_T::value_type;` should work

Comment: @NathanPierson Wow if that's try that's ultra useful

Comment: Your approach would require `std::declval` too.  Yet another would be to pattern-match with a partial specialization, but that’s obviously not necessary in this case.

Comment: @Zebrafish All standard containers define a `value_type` member.

Comment: @NathanPierson You should write an answer with exactly your comment text.

Answer (score 4):

I don't believe you need any of the complexity in the current answer.

You can get the type of an optional with `Optional_T::value_type`

The type is listed here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional